# How do I use GetComponent on multiple children?

Tags: unity

I'm a beginner and I'm making a game in Unity where I set random colors for four enemies. I made an empty object called "enemies" for me to use it as a folder for the four enemies. I want to get the colors of the enemies and pick randomly one of them for my player.

I wrote this piece of code and I wanted it to store the colors in a list, but whenever I try to print it I find out that it only stores the color of the first child in the "enemies" hierarchy. How do I fix this?

```
enemies = GameObject.Find("enemies");

GameObject[] allenemies = new GameObject[enemies.transform.childCount];
List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();

foreach (Transform child in transform)
{
    allenemies[i] = child.gameObject;
    i++;
}

foreach (GameObject child in allenemies)
{
    thecolor = enemies.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color;
    colors.Add(thecolor);
}

finalcolor = Random.Range(0, colors.Count);
//Debug.Log(finalcolor);

mr.material.color = colors[finalcolor];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetComponentInChildren` [returns only a single component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) (the first four item in a depth-first search).

[The `Component` API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) has a similar method called [`GetComponentsInChildren()` which returns an array containing all the relevant components](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html).

You'll need to adapt your code slightly to use this, for example by calling `colors.AddRange()` to add the returned array to your color list.